# Prove that $a_n= \frac{\cos(x)}{3} + \frac{\cos(2x)}{3^2}+\ldots+\frac{\cos(nx)}{3^n}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

### Prove that $a_n= \frac{\cos(x)}{3} + \frac{\cos(2x)}{3^2}+\ldots+\frac{\cos(nx)}{3^n}$ is Cauchy ($x$ is a coefficient)

According to the definition I calculated $|a_{n+p}-a_n|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n+p} \frac{\cos(kx)}{3^k} -\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\cos(kx)}{3^k}\right| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \frac{\cos(kx)}{3^k}\right| \leq \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{3^{n+1}}+\ldots+ \frac{1}{3^{n+p}}=\frac{1}{3^{n+1}} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3^{p-1}}\right)$

the term in the brackets is a geometric series  so we can calculate the sum

$\frac{1}{3^{n+1}} \cdot \left(\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{p-1}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\right)=\frac{1}{3^{n+1}} \cdot \left(\frac{3}{2} - \frac{3}{2 \cdot 3^{p-1}}\right)= \frac{3}{2 \cdot 3^{n+1}} \cdot \left(1- \frac{1}{3^{p-1}}\right)$

from here I could not continue I tried comparing and got to $\frac{3}{2 \cdot 3 ^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3^n}< \frac{1}{3^n} < \varepsilon$ and since $n>N$ I got $\frac{1}{3^n} < \frac{1}{3^N} < \varepsilon$

but I was not sure on how to continue or if I am on the right track

Thanks for any help and tips

Comment: We have $1-\frac{1}{3^{p-1}}<1$. That way you get rid of $p$. So indeed, for any $n.p$ we have $|a_{n+p}-a_n|\leq\frac{1}{3^n}$. Now check when this becomes less than $\epsilon$, and choose $N$ accordingly.

Comment: It's likely overkill, but the partial sums of this series can be written explicitly: $$\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{3^n}\cos(nx)=\frac{1-3\cos x-3^{-k}(\cos(kx)-\cos[(k+1)x]}{6\cos x-10}$$
which converges to $(1-3\cos x)/(6\cos x-10)$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @Semiclassical :D